# Command action for strike summons/minion

Tags: druid, animal-companions, summoning, pathfinder-2e

Wonder if someone could help. I have created a pathfinder 2e Druid character with an animal companion (Bear) and a Summon Fey spell (Sprite).
Can the bear only attack my enemy when commanded?

From page **214** - Pathfinder 2e Core Rulebook:

> Your animal companion has the minion trait, and it gains 2 actions during your turn if you use the Command an Animal action to command it

while the summoned Sprite does **not** require the command

From page **637** - Pathfinder 2e Core Rulebook:

> generally attacks your enemies to the best of its abilities

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I think your question would be improved by making it clear which text is being quoted where.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Summoned creatures are minions.

And therefore, they must be commanded to get actions.

The chain of looking this up for yourself:

1. [Summon Fey](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=322) is a Conjuration spell that says you summon a creature
2. The [Conjuration School](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=263) of magic notes that "creatures summoned by conjuration spells have the summoned trait."
3. [Summoned](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=154) states that "It has the minion trait."

Note that for summoned minions, the Sustain a Spell action to keep the creature summoned doubles as the action to command it (as noted in the [Minion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=109) trait)

---

And from this, Minions only get actions when you spend actions to command them, unless they have an ability which allows them to take some actions otherwise (like Rangers' Mature animal companions, who may be able to spend an action against the Hunted Prey):

> Your minion acts on your turn in combat, once per turn, when you spend an action to issue it commands.

Which states that it only acts when you spend the action.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the chain of lookup for next time :)

Comment: Druids have a feat with the same name, without the Hunt Prey requirement. Fits better for the answer.